# Why does Angular not update the UI onInit?

Tags: angular

I want to check if the user is logged in and display/hide the login button based on a boolean value. But for some reason, the button is always displayed.
This is the app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ip-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

 loggedIn: boolean = false;

 constructor(
   private translateService: TranslateService,
   private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
   public dialog: MatDialog
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.authenticationService.checkLogin();
   this.authenticationService.loggedIn.subscribe(loggedIn => this.loggedIn = loggedIn);
 }
}
```

This is app.component.html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
<app-navigation></app-navigation>
    <button *ngIf="!loggedIn" mat-raised-button (click)="openLoginDialog()">{{'authentication.login' | translate}}</button>
</mat-toolbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

This is the authentication.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  public loggedIn: Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }
  
  checkLogin(): void {
    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'access_token': accessToken});
    this.httpClient.post(url, null, {headers}).subscribe(result => this.loggedIn.next(true));
  }

}
```

The service is part of the authentication.module.ts which is imported to app.component.ts. I already tried marking it as singleton with providedIn: 'root', but that didn't work. The funny thing is, that if I click on the login button, it disappears, but I want to make it disappear on the loading of the page.

Comment: Well, does the `loggedIn` BehaviorSubject emit true? If you console.log or call `debugger` in the subscription callback inside OnInit, does the log appear? Do you have OnPush change detection in some of your components? It seems to me the Change Detection is not running.

Comment: Yes, the loggedIn emits to true, I already checked with a console.log. How does OnPush work? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Mmmm... if you are working on the main AppComponent of the application, it's probably not related to OnPush (https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4 is a very nice guide on the argument). You can try calling `ChangeDetectorRef.markForCheck` in an injected ChangeDetectorRef, or inserting the body of the onInit into a settimeout call, just to make sure if it's a timing problem.

Comment: Okay, inserting it into a settimeout actually solved the issue, but now the button pops up for a second and then disappears. How can I solve this timing issue? Would it help to extract the login-button to another module/component?

Comment: settimout / 0 on ngAfterViewInit

Comment: That actually didn't help, but using ChangeDetectorRef solved the issue. Thank you very much :)